# Docker and M1 chip Mac

Tags: docker, apple-m1, rosetta-2

I was trying to run a test after installing a Nextflow pipeline (Eager) that uses the Docker and I got this error message:
nf-core/eager execution completed unsuccessfully!
The exit status of the task that caused the workflow execution to fail was: null.

```
The full error message was:

Error executing process > 'fastqc (JK2802_L2)'

Caused by:
  Process exceeded running time limit (10m)

Command executed:

  fastqc -t 2 -q JK2802_AGAATAACCTACCA_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz.tengrand.fq.gz
  rename 's/_fastqc\.zip$/_raw_fastqc.zip/' *_fastqc.zip
  rename 's/_fastqc\.html$/_raw_fastqc.html/' *_fastqc.html

Command exit status:
  -

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested

Work dir:
  /Users/valentina/test/work/de/5948543b4928857decf6b62407b17f

Tip: you can try to figure out what's wrong by changing to the process work dir and showing the script file named `.command.sh`
```

After reading around I have thought that the problem could be because of Rosetta2 not being installed properly. I did run this command before installing the Docker `softwareupdate --install-rosetta` as suggested in their website (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/) but I get this message:

```
I have read and agree to the terms of the software license agreement. A list of Apple SLAs may be found here: http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/
Type A and press return to agree: A
2023-09-06 13:56:22.250 softwareupdate[4076:29579] Package Authoring Error: 042-15018: Package reference com.apple.pkg.RosettaUpdateAuto is missing installKBytes attribute
Install of Rosetta 2 finished successfully
```

1. I see several Rosetta2 applications listed in the System Report -> Software -> Applications.
2. I have tried to install the update for Rosetta2 in /System/Library/CoreServices but it fails.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I'd consider building the image for arm -- that way you don't need Rosetta at all, and will get much better performance.

Comment: Thanks. I really do not know how to do this. Would you be able to help me please? Thanks