# Building the image for arm to make Docker working

Tags: docker, arm, apple-m1, nextflow

I am trying to run a bioinformatic pipeline (Nextflow - Eager) that uses Docker but as I have a Mac M1 chip it does not work and I get this error message:

```
Command error:
  WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
```

I know that I should build the image for arm but I am not sure I am doing it correctly.
I have tried to `vim ~/.nextflow/config` and add `docker.runOptions = '-u $(id -u):$(id -g) --platform=linux/amd64'` then run the pipeline again with this command: `nextflow run nf-core/eager -r 2.4.6 -profile test,docker` but I still get this error:

```
Execution cancelled -- Finishing pending tasks before exit
Error executing process > 'adapter_removal (JK2782_L1)'
Caused by:
 Process exceeded running time limit (10m)
Command executed:
 mkdir -p output
  
 AdapterRemoval --file1 JK2782_TGGCCGATCAACGA_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz.tengrand.fq.gz --file2 JK2782_TGGCCGATCAACGA_L008_R2_001.fastq.gz.tengrand.fq.gz --basename JK2782_TGGCCGATCAACGA_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz.tengrand.fq_L1.pe --gzip --threads 2 --qualitymax 41 --collapse --trimns --trimqualities --adapter1 AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCAC --adapter2 AGATCGGAAGAGCGTCGTGTAGGGAAAGAGTGTA --minlength 30 --minquality 20 --minadapteroverlap 1
  
 cat *.collapsed.gz *.collapsed.truncated.gz *.singleton.truncated.gz *.pair1.truncated.gz *.pair2.truncated.gz > output/JK2782_TGGCCGATCAACGA_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz.tengrand.fq_L1.pe.combined.tmp.fq.gz
  
 mv *.settings output/
  
 ## Add R_ and L_ for unmerged reads for DeDup compatibility
 AdapterRemovalFixPrefix -Xmx4g output/JK2782_TGGCCGATCAACGA_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz.tengrand.fq_L1.pe.combined.tmp.fq.gz | pigz -p 1 > output/JK2782_TGGCCGATCAACGA_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz.tengrand.fq_L1.pe.combined.fq.gz
Command exit status:
 -
Command output:
 (empty)
Command error:
 WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
 Trimming paired end reads ...
 Opening FASTQ file 'JK2782_TGGCCGATCAACGA_L008_R1_001.fastq.gz.tengrand.fq.gz', line numbers start at 1
 Opening FASTQ file 'JK2782_TGGCCGATCAACGA_L008_R2_001.fastq.gz.tengrand.fq.gz', line numbers start at 1
  
 Processed a total of 20,000 reads in 1.0s; 19,000 reads per second on average ...
Work dir:
 /Users/valentina/test2/work/11/83eeaec751248909302745eca1e24f
Tip: when you have fixed the problem you can continue the execution adding the option `-resume` to the run command line
```

How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker on Mac M1 gives: "The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69054921/docker-on-mac-m1-gives-the-requested-images-platform-linux-amd64-does-not-m)

Comment: Are you using a ready-made image?  Which image?  Have you a `Dockerfile`?  Please, provide more infos.  BTW, the error message about wrong platform appears also in the question you posted yesterday at https://stackoverflow.com/q/77053095/685806 so it's the same problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying and being patient. I am using a Nextflow pipeline that I did not develop so I guess that I am using a ready-made image. In my docker images folder I see one called nfcore/eager also displaying a warning tag (!) "AMD64". One of the developer told me to do manual arm profile by making a config file in ~/.nextflow/ and specifying with docker.runOptions = '-u $(id -u):$(id -g) --platform=linux/amd64' which I did but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mac M1 is an ARM64 processor but `nfcore/eager` is available for AMD64 only.
The M1 *should* be capable of running AMD64 images too thanks to an emulator called Rosetta (see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67458621/685806)) but someone says (see [this page](https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues/4037)):

> you'll never be happy using any amd64 components in Docker on a mac
> M1. Docker Desktop (and only Docker Desktop) went way out of its way
> to try to be able to run amd64 components, but it really doesn't work
> out in general.

At least you should verify that you have a recent version of Docker Desktop and also the Rosetta emulator or install it; the installation of Rosetta can de done with:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

as explained [in Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/#system-requirements).  Note that I have not a Mac so I cannot be more specific on this topic.  I also don't know the bioinformatic tools you are using so I cannot confirm that the right way of forcing the use of the AMD64 image is editing `~/.nextflow/config`, but it seems that the answer is no because the error message still says "no specific platform was requested".

Since you are not running Docker directly but through another tool called `nextflow` you could try to use the solution suggested [in this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65612411/forcing-docker-to-use-linux-amd64-platform-by-default-on-macos):

```
export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
```

An alternative solution is to rebuild the image for ARM64 but it's not a trivial task. I succeded in rebuilding the AMD64 image but got an error with the ARM64 image: it seems that some prerequisite is not met but I cannot do more without knowing this bionformatic tool.

Comment: Thanks. I did install rosetta indeed but it was still not working. I have now also set the environment variable. The pipeline still does not work properly but now I get a bunch of different errors...the solution for me now is to use another computer running with linux. Thanks anyway